# Determining all functions $f(z+c)=-1/(f(z)+1)$

Tags: periodic-functions

I've noticed in my free time when the functional mapping $f(z+c)=-1/(f(z)+1)$ is iterated twice, it yields the original function $f(z)$ (i.e. $f(z+3c)=f(z)$). So I thought to study it as a periodic function...but I don't know enough about it to evaluate its Fourier series. I went back to its original equation, and saw that if it had a zero (I'll call it $\alpha$), it would also have a singularity at $\alpha-c$; I realized that likewise if $f(z)$ doesn't vanish it can't have any singularities (but I'm not sure that's possible since its equation cannot be satisfied by an exponential function).

I would like to know the most general kind of function $f(z)$ can be. It looks to me like a trigonometric function could describe it...but nothing appears to disqualify it having a second period. I am assuming $f(z)$ is meromorphic and continuous in the interval $(0,c)$, and I'm allowing $c$ to be complex (though not forcing it).

Comment: How are you getting that f is periodic?

Comment: yes with $h(z) = \frac{-1}{z+1}$ we have $h(h(h(z))) = z$, so $f(x+3c) = h(h(h(f(x)))) = f(x)$ @TimRaczkowski

Comment: Ah I see how you got that.

Comment: If $x$ is real, assign any values to $f$ on $[0,c)$, and set the rest such that it fulfills your equation, I don't see what you can say more. Now if $x$ is a complex number $\in U$ and $f$ is meromorphic on $U$, it could be different

Comment: I _am_ considering $f$ to be a meromorphic function, and $x\in\mathbb{C}$, so I can determine the most general form for $f(x)$. If I, say, set $f(0)=0$, then I could say $f(x)$ includes $\sin(2\pi x/(3\alpha))$ and, due to my equation, $1/\sin(2\pi x/(3\alpha)-2\pi/3)$.

Comment: You should add the meromorphic hypothesis to the question itself. Right now you don't even ask for $f$ to be continuous, so one can simply set arbitrary values for every $x$ with $0\le\Re(x)<c$. (Is $c$ positive? real?) For that matter, it's more suggestive to use $z$ instead of $x$, if you mean the input to be complex.

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in my calculations and it now doesn't seem dolvable anymore for me, but I don't want to completely delete the andere.

First of all, let $x_0$ be a solution of $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
x^2+x+1=0 \iff x(x+1)=-1 \iff x = - \frac{1}{x+1}.
\end{align*}
Thus, $f(z) = x_0$ is a solution for your problem. Now
\begin{align*}
f'(z) = f'(z-c+c) = -(\frac{1}{f(z-c)+1})' = \frac{f'(z - c)}{(f(z-c)+1)^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: I see how you got $x^2+x+1=0$, but how did you get $f'(z)$ in the numerator of $-(-1/(f(z-c)+1))'$? Shouldn't it be instead $f'(z-c)$?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake there. Then I have no idea how to solve it :/

Comment: I'll look at how $f(z)$ can have zeros and poles, since its functional equation implies they'll have the same order.